# Uniform.js - changing the background of select menus

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-uniform

Is there a way to change the background of select menus with uniform.js?  I changed my body background to a dark color and now all the select menus have that color in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I found the style in uniform.css, so fixed now.

```
div.selector select {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background:  #fafaee;
  position: absolute;
  height: 22px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%; }
```